# Django honeypot error template customization

Tags: python, django, honeypot

I am using Django honeypot (https://github.com/jamesturk/django-honeypot) and was wondering how to customize the honeypot_error.html page (https://github.com/jamesturk/django-honeypot/blob/master/honeypot/templates/honeypot/honeypot_error.html), which is executed when honeypot detection gets tripped. Thanks!!

Comment: why not just edit honeypot_error.html to provide whatever you want?

Answer (score 1):

if you had `honeypot_error.html` with the same structured path
`templates/honeypot/honeypot_error.html` in your project it will take your page as default. (see the key point to note: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template) )

example:
package x define a template named `toto.html` in `templates/myapp/toto.html`

in your application, add a customized `toto.html` in `templates/myapp/toto.html`

when calling

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

it will get your template and not the one provided by default by myapp

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on MSR974's answer so:

From Django's documentation on [overriding templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/):

```py
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'blog',
    ...,
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

Notice: "If you have app and project templates directories that both contain overrides, the default Django template loader will try to load the template from the project-level directory first. In other words, **DIRS is searched before APP_DIRS**."

As you read through the examples, keep in mind the distinction between APP and PROJECT templates and make sure you've configured your SETTINGS according to the chosen strategy.

Comment: yeah, it just means that if your app is in a parent folder and the parent folder contains  a template which exist in your app too, the parent folder's template will be loaded first.  
In OP case, the template he want to customize is provided by a pip package.